# using phpfile output inside js file file as variable

Tags: javascript, php

Recently I am learning single page application, but I got a problem, the project I am working on is inside a folder that contain many folders, php js are folders in side the main folder, and each contain its type of files, the problem is that one of the php file called `getmax.php` gives me the maximum id ,I want to use this `max(id)` in a js file called `module.js` in order to give the new module the next id , the `module.js` should gives this id to another php file called `insert.php` ,the connection between the `module.js` and `insert.php` is working properly if I set the id manually . but I could not figure out how can I make it use the `max(id)` from the `getmax.php` file.

note: I noticed lately I'm using MySQL and I should used `mysqli` I will fix it later.

the `getmax.php` is:

```
<?php
// alle relevanten Tabellen abfragen und als json zurückgeben.


$json["status"] = "running";
$details[] = "started get_tables ";
// Include confi.php
include_once('confi.php');
//var_dump($_POST);
$request_body = file_get_contents('php://input');
// first store the given set of data to keep it for future analysis
$statement = "INSERT INTO tbl_archive (content) VALUES ('$request_body' );";
mysql_query($statement);
$input = json_decode($request_body, true);
// now check if valid user
$user = $input["user"];

$username = $user["username"];
$password = $user["password"];

if($password and $username){


    $mySQLstring = "SELECT username, password, id, create_user FROM tbl_user where username = '$username' ;";
    $json["statement"][] = $mySQLstring;
    $qur = mysql_query($mySQLstring);
    //var_dump ( $qur );
    if ($qur){
        $max = mysql_fetch_assoc($qur);
    }
    if ($max){
        $json["max"] = $max;
        if ($max["password"] == $password){
            $json["username"] = $username;
            $json["id"] = $max["id"];
            $json["create_user"] = $max["create_user"];
            $json["status"] = "ok";
            $tables = array("class", "class_user", "module", "module_class", "module_user", "rating", "student", "student_class");
            //$tables = array("class");
            foreach($tables as $table){
                if ( $table == 'module' ){
                $statement ='SELECT create_user, MAX(id) FROM tbl_'.$table;                 

                //$statement .= ' GROUP BY create_user' ;
                $statement .= ' WHERE create_user = 19 ' ;

                $qur = mysql_query($statement);
                if ($qur){
                    while($r = mysql_fetch_array($qur, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
                        //var_dump($r);
                        //echo (json_encode($r));
                        $result[$table][] = $r;
                    }
                }
                }
            }
            $json = array("status" => "ok", "data" => $result);
        }
    }
}



@mysql_close($conn);

/* Output header */
header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: To get value from php to javascript you can use AJAX .

Answer (score 1):

PHP and JS are run on the server and client respectively, and as such you cannot call methods/functions of one from the other. AJAX exists to pass values between JS and serverside code.

Comment: do you know any website or maybe on youtube that teach ajax simply and clearly?